# Why should I use webpack loaders?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, loader

Two days ago I've learned about webpack loaders. After 6-7 youtube videos and several hours of practice I know how to use them. But not a single tutorial explained, why should I. They say "We can just add  tag and add css there, but let's do it using loaders". So now I know what loaders are and how to use them. But... Why? What benefits are here? What can I do with webpack css- and style-loaders and cannot using ? Or is it better for performance to have css written is js file? What bothers me more is to use loaders for img files, fonts and other files. All loaders do in this case is just change the names and put them into "dist" folder. Why cannot I just put the images I need into that folder manually, why use loaders (I don't speak about compression of files here, because I'm not sure yet if I am able to compress imgs with loaders). So my question is, why loaders? Especially, why loaders for imgs and other files, if I just might as well put them into dist folder myself? What are benefits which I cannot see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you do so you can bundle them up. For example, say you want to work with SASS. You build up your SCSS code, now you have to produce the CSS file and add it up to your html files. Now, if you have a loader, `webpack` can compile the CSS file for you and bundle it up with your javascript code. So now you don't have to manage `style` tags as the javascript code will do that for you. Say you have typescript code. That also needs compiling and probably bundled up.

Do you need loaders? They are not exactly required but the alternative is doing everything manually. As per CSS, fonts, images, etc.. You have to understand that Webpack is all about creating a bundle. So it can pick assets and bundles them up. Could you do it manually? Also yes, but then again, that's what Webpack does.

Comment: So, nothing special that I've missed? Well... that's also fine. Just to clearfy, webpack will not compress images or make some useful magic, it will just literally put the images in dist folder for me? And thank you for the answer, it helped me

Comment: It will depend on the loader. There's no magic either. You can compress your images manually.