# Why use webpack loaders?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, loader

I am learning some webpack because I am also learning Angular and I have read this framework uses webpack. Also I have read it can help with performance with non Angular apps.

I made a very simple test with only displays an image

**index.html**

```
<img id="imagen">
<script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
```

To learn how loaders work, I made it with loader and without it.

**script.js without loader**

```
let myImagen=document.getElementById("imagen");

myImagen.src='./img/ball.jpg';
```

And this is the performance when I bundle it into `main.js`

[image]

We have a request for the `main.js` and another for the image.

After that I tested it using [this loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

**script.js with file-loader**

```
import imagen from './img/ball.jpg';

let myImagen=document.getElementById("imagen");

myImagen.src=imagen;
```

And this is the performance obtained, just the same requests ( the image name is changed by loader)

[image]

Thing is, apart from having the file automatically uploaded to the `dist` folder when I use the loader, which is the advantage of using it? I see img is not compressed, and I have not less requests or a better performance or something like that (thought image would be somewhow bundled into `main.js` by the loader).

Si I don´t know which is the real purpose on struggling with this
.

I have been looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053174/why-should-i-use-webpack-loaders) but the accepted answer doesn´t clarify for me at all. Ok maybe with CSS is different (must test it), and you can bundle it into the js then you save some requests... as I said, I will test it. But for things like images, I can´t see the advantage.

Comment: _At its core, webpack is a static module bundler for modern JavaScript applications. When webpack processes your application, it internally builds a dependency graph from one or more entry points and then combines every module your project needs into one or more bundles, which are static assets to serve your content from._ (definition from webpack)
It's not there to increase performance, but to bundle your application. the way you write your application doesn't necessarily mean it's the way you serve it.

Comment: It *can* also increase performance.  If I remember right, if some images are under a certain file size, they will be base64 encoded and inlined meaning no request is actually made.  Loaders are also there to help with the pipelining of certain file types.  Sure, images are pretty straight-forward, but transpiling TS and mapping Markdown to HTML isn't and has quite a bit of tedious boilerplate.

Comment: Performance might refer to *bundle splitting* where you defer loading code until it's actually needed, thus keeping the size of the code to download initially small.

Comment: @zero298 i tested with css and style loader and it seems it saves the css requests as well as the css kinking tag on .html, so I guess in that case it increases performance isn´t it? Specially on an app where you could have many .css sheets...